# substr gives empty results in PHP

Tags: php, substr

I want to get the last 41 letters of a string, but every time its giving me a empty result.
The string is following:

```
02674bf7c88c9a025029f96d046651cfsingle100OK4917668157533262-07119519DEE0715DD708E6B65BC2412E1A8EE571F
```

Here is my code:

```
$urlstring = $_GET["o"];  
$password = "bla"; 
$salt = "bla";    
$result = decode($password, $urlstring, $salt); 
if (strpos($result,'OK') !== false) {
    $uservar = substr($result, -41); 
    $file = 'file.txt';
    file_put_contents($file,$uservar);
}
```

Comment: Your $result variable has the string you've pointed out in your question, right?

Comment: yes @taxiscala, as you can see it contains the word "OK" so its writing the file. But its empty. The $result is getting by the o parameter at the top of the code and works fine.

Comment: does file.txt have the proper read/write permissions in your server?

Comment: i guess so. if i only write the $result in the .txt file without substr its writing the string in the file. @taxicala

Comment: maybe you know another way to get the number behind the dash "-"

Comment: Only one dash always in your string?

Comment: For that use `list($before_dash, $after_dash) = explode('-', $string);`

Comment: Use `var_dump()` to see what is in your variables. When something like this happens you must look at what is *actually* going on; not what you *think* is going on.

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen how do i use vardump? use it with a variable? And where do i see the results?

Comment: @mav Just put variables in it, like `var_dump($var1, $var2, [...])`. See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php).

Comment: @SverriM.Olsen where do i see the output? im running the file on my ftp. sorry but in this stuff im very new.

Comment: @mav You should see it in your browser window (it is outputted just like anything else).

Comment: im getting the "o" variable from a payment provider. Its sending the variable to my php file. So after i do a payment the variable will be sending out. So i open the my phpfile from my webspace on my browser and i will see the vardump echo? @SverriM.Olsen

Comment: It's strange. I put the decoded string you provided into `$result` and copy-pasted the rest of the code into a file, ran it and it generated a 41 bytes `file.txt` containing the expected substring. There is no problem with the code. As long as `$result` is not empty, the only situation when [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) with two arguments returns something that is `empty()` (`''` or `FALSE`) is when the length of the string is smaller than `$start` (the second argument of `substr()`) and this is impossible when `$start` is negative.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? If it is between (and including) 5.2.2 and 5.2.6 then you are out of luck. `substr()` with negative length was buggy on those versions (it's explained in the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php#refsect1-function.substr-changelog)).

Comment: My PHP Version is  5.3.29 @axiac

Comment: @axiac is there any other way to get the last 41 letters?

Answer (score 0):

Actually

```
$uservar = substr($result, -41);
```

does that, i.e. it will return last 41 chars. The problem most likely is that your decode function doesn't work and you never enter the if

```
$result = decode($password, $urlstring, $salt); 
if (strpos($result,'OK') !== false) {   // check if $result contains OK
    $uservar = explode('-', $result); 
    $file = 'file.txt';
    file_put_contents($file, $uservar[1]);
}
```

Comment: But my decode function works. The String witch is send by request is crypted. That is my string: `without decrypting my string looks like that 3aQhIkUkaFyqyq9OxdXYhw1a2YnE7%2Fn4c2zKLzwKxy35skKjV0cUYWimO9amxIV5pcEbGBHC%2Fby%‌​2FSQij1O%2BWF5hidckqSE6ZaYHnqnTcn4CtYAyW1YIpJt0B8j9e5VEn42OF5FXty0RJe%2BCB%2B7B8K‌​cLAgDQNKTeV9IsLaQiw3EmHCexVfu%2FjqacAhXLVwfYLXeVQiQvmNeAWZCh7ONcw8ti%2FgzFY99IPxl‌​73frNOascgXipkYqvV2IwKnf74dwy%2Fl9wg7MQn6k01bQwhrvr%2BNe7bO%2Bbe4Rwik6yyhP8WXwlAF‌​HxrxuAkM6aE9%2BwddT%2B04Lub8ehZduwbhsws0sDUBbGjGqPCrFsa90gOcRWfEJMQ%3D%3D`

Comment: An the if is entered because its reads the "OK" from the string i posted in my start post. Otherwise it wouldnt create the file.txt. And with your code its still empty.

Answer (score 0):

Change the folder permission to 777, and test the code again.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to get the last part of the `$result` string provided in the question.

#### a) substr()

The function [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) is the most straightforward way to do it (as you already did).

```
$uservar = substr($result, -41);
```

#### b) regular expressions: preg_replace()

You can use [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to match the last 41 characters of the string into a group and replace the entire string with the group:

```
$uservar = preg_replace('/^.*(.{41})$/', '$1', $result);
```

The regular expression used for search:

- `^` is the beginning of the string;
- `.*` is any character (`.`), zero or more times (`*`);
- `(.{41})` is any character (`.`), 41 times (`{41}`); the parentheses around the expression make a subpattern that can be used later in the `regex` or in the replacement string (as `$1`);
- `$` is the end of the string.

It matches any string that is at least 41 characters length; its last 41 characters are grouped in the first subpattern.

The replacement string (`$1`) refers to the 1st subpattern of the `regex`. It makes `preg_replace()` replace the matched string (the entire string) with its first subpattern (its last 41 characters). Read more about the [PCRE patterns syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.syntax.php).

#### c) convert the string to array of characters

Convert the string into an array of characters ([`str_split()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-split.php)), extract the correct slice of array ([`array_slice()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php)), join the characters back ([`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)).

```
$uservar = implode('', array_slice(str_split($result), -41));
```

This solution works the same as `substr()`.

#### d) split the string into pieces using delimiter

If you are sure that the part of the string you need to extract does not contain any dash (`-`) and it starts right after the last dash then we don't even need to know its length. Use [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) to split `$result` into pieces delimited by dash (`-`) and the last piece is the part you need:

```
// Split the string into pieces
$pieces = explode('-', $result);
// Remove the last item from $pieces and return it
$uservar = array_pop($pieces);
// Alternatively, without modifying $pieces:
$uservar = end($pieces);
// Or
$uservar = $pieces[count($piece)-1];
```

#### e) ...

With little imagination, more complicated ways to extract a part of the string can be produced in a couple of lines of code.

### Conclusion

Given `$result` is a not-empty string whose length is at least 41, all the above should work and produce the same result. The `preg_replace()` solution won't work for shorter strings (can be easily changed to work), the `explode()` solution doesn't care about `41` but uses `-` to separate the pieces.

If none of them works then your problem is somewhere else. Check for file rights, check if the code enters the `if` branch etc.